# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

Could you please let me know where I have to correct the statement.

```
     $(function(){
      $('#buttonclick').click(function(){
          // if(!$('#iframe1').length) {
                  $('#submitbutton').html('<iframe id="iframe1"  src="{{ url_for('stream') }}" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"> </iframe>');
          // }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you using a framework that replaces `{{ url_for('stream') }}` with something? Please tag with the framework.

Comment: If yo uclick on the line number in the error message, it will take you directly to the location of the problem and highlight it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#buttonclick').click(function(){
        // if(!$('#iframe1').length) {
        $('#submitbutton').html(`<iframe id="iframe1"  src="${ url_for('stream') }" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;width:100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"> </iframe>`);
        // }
    });
});
```

Comment: You only have to escape quotes that are the same as the original string delimiter. So you don't need backslashes before the double quotes.

Comment: I believe the `{{url_for(...)}}` stuff is replaced by the framework before JavaScript sees it, so those quotes shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: Maybe using backticks would be better?

Comment: `${url_for('string')}` is not correct. It's not a JavaScript function, it's something implemented by the template framework. That's what `{{}}` means

Comment: @Barmar I am not familiar with such framework. I assumed the function was defined elsewhere, though imported and ready to use in the OP's context.

Comment: I don't know what framework it is, but it's almost certainly something like that. That's why I asked the OP to add a tag for this to the question.

Comment: I am defining the url for stream in the python flask code:   @Barmar                                                    

It is loading correctly and displaying logs in the first instance but later when I reload the server it is not working. Maybe I will try using another methods to handle this. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: The code I wrote for stream in the flask is below:                                                       
@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    my_file = Path("log.txt")
    if my_file.is_file():
        with open("log.txt", "r") as f:
            content = f.read()
    else:
        content = " "
    # as you see, file is loaded only once, no loop here, (loop is on frontend side)
    return app.response_class(content, mimetype='text/plain')

Comment: @MehrdadMoradi it removed the error. thanks